# Enable Ctrl+ScrollWheel in SlickEdit

Tags: slickedit

How do you enable SlickEdit to zoom in and out of text by pressing the ctrl key and scrolling the mousewheel?

This exists in basically every other editor I've used but sadly we're stuck with this garbage at work.

Answer (score 1):

Tools, Options, Keyboard and Mouse, Keybindings. Scroll down to command wfont-zoom-in and wfont-zoom out. Add keybinding. Hit apply.